# Interfacing a joypad in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, directx

How does one interface a joypad under Windows?

Is there a WinAPI method, or must DirectX be used?  Can anyone provide some pointers as to how to get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the multimedia API in mmsystem.h.  joyGetNumDevs() to discover joystick numbers, joyGetPos() to get the position.  SDK docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757116%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Got the joystick working and driving my servos within minutes.